# Legacy context API React with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

i`m using react + react-router-dom. My code shows this message in console

```
The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version.

Please update the following components: Consumer, Provider

Learn more about this warning here: https://reactjs.org/link/legacy-context
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:2330:26)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:4062:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:3682:35)
    at div
    at App
```

I am using just 2 files (that i changed or added)

```
import React  from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Routers } from "./routers"


export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Routers />
            </Router>
        </div>
  );
}
```

and file with Routers

```
import React from "react";

import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export const Routers = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/main">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Is it means, what library has old version or i can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have specified in your `package.json`?

Comment: oh, i mixed up different packages.js server and client. Now everything seems to be installed correctly, it works. Version is "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",